# How to remove existing record line items in the sales order in nesuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I m very new to netsuite,i m trying to remove all line items in the latest existing sales order .How can i do this in UserEventAfterSubmit function.
Thanks.

Comment: try loading the record, simply remove all line items one by one and submit the record.

Answer (score 3):

Use `UserEventBeforeSubmit` instead of `UserEventAfterSubmit`.

Try this :

```
var lineCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
    for (var i = lineCount;i>=1; i--) {
    nlapiRemoveLineItem('item', i);
    }
```

**Note**

Make sure that the line items you want to delete must not associated with any transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove line items on client script, if you try to remove lines on user event, you need add other item.

in this case I remove items when the unit is in "EA".

```
function removeEa(){

  jQuery("[id*='item_row_']").each(function(e) {
  var line = jQuery(this).attr('id').split('item_row_')[1];
  var unit = jQuery(this).children().text().indexOf('EA') != -1;
  if(unit){
  nlapiRemoveLineItem('item', line);
  }

 })

 }
```

if you want remove lines in one user event you need add other line item is a new requirment for the new release.

Good luck